# DB::raw convert to query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Can you help me to convert the Raw part of my query to use query builder?
I am stuck at joining it all together:

```php
$profile = UserProfiles::select('id')->where('alias', $profileAlias)->first();

$dbRawMessagesCount = '
  (SELECT COUNT(pm.id) 
  FROM profile_messages pm 
  WHERE pm.to_profile_id='.$profile->id.' 
     AND pm.from_profile_id=profile_friend.id 
     AND pm.is_read=0) AS messages_count
';

$friends = ProfileFriend::select('profile_friend.*', DB::raw($dbRawMessagesCount))
    ->with('friendProfile')
    ->whereHas('ownerProfile', function ($query) use ($profile) {
        return $query->where('id', $profile->id);
    })
    ->orderBy('messages_count')
    ->paginate();
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little clearer the expected result? :) any extra context would be helpful.

Comment: i suppose he got raw SQL and want rewrite it in query builder format. you see he count there some messages by SQL means and then uses that field to orderBy

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite this into one query if `ProfileFriend` has a relation already set up to `ProfileMessages` using `withCount()` in the query.

```
$friends = ProfileFriend::with('friendProfile')
    ->withCount(['profileMessages' => function($q) use($profile){
        $q->where('to_profile_id', $profile->id)->where('is_read', 0); 
        // No longer need 'from_profile_id' as it is already querying the relationship
    }])
    ->whereHas('ownerProfile', function ($query) use ($profile) {
        return $query->where('id', $profile->id);
    })
    ->paginate();
```

Now if you `dd($friends->first())` you will notice it has a field called `profileMessages_count` that gives you a count of what I'm assuming is unread messages.

Comment: your solution count messages according to the received rows, kind of you are receiving 50 unread messages as a collection and then by means of php count will be counted number of elements in array.
in original question there paid attention to count number of messages by means of  SQL, i suppose to later order by number of unread messages
but in your solution further order by number of unread messages is pretty problematic ? (without loop over received results especially when it comes to the pagination)

Comment: I'm not certain what you are asking. This adds a property to the model that contains the count of the relationship.

Comment: how to sort according to the received count in offered way? for example i want to sort results desc according to the number of messages and the rest according to the last name

Comment: Since it's a property on the model you can use the collection method `sortByDesc('profileMessages_count')->sortBy('last_name')` to get the list sorted in the way that makes sense. Any messages with unread content will be at the top of the list, and then the rest of the list will be sorted by last name.